# Skipping configuration of projects that do not need compiling

Tags: linux, bash, unix, makefile, autotools

I'm running a long build script compiling a lot of projects, and for most builds `make` usually returns with `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'`, which is good because I'm not changing that much code on every build. The script still takes a long time to finish, however, simply because it calls autotools `configure`script for each project, and some other scripts.

I've read somewhere that make uses timestamps to test if it needs to build.

Is there a way to ask Make if it needs to build or not before calling the `configure` script?
Or maybe another way to prevent re-configuring of all projects?

Comment: How exactly is `configure` being run? It sounds like either it does not need to be run as part of the Makefile, or that it should have a dependency to prevent it from running when unnecessary.

Comment: You're right about the configure script. There are however other scripts running that I'd like to disable if there is no need for that project to compile. Edited the question

Comment: Well, the same thing applies. It seems that your Makefile is running some things unconditionally that really should be assigned dependencies so that `make` knows when they do not need to be run.

Comment: Sounds good! I thought of the using `make`'s answer on whether it needs to build or not as the condition of running the other scripts. How can I do it otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having configured each project once, you do not need to run each `configure` script again unless those `configure` scripts themselves change, or you have reason to believe that the test results will have changed.  If necessary, you can run `config.status` instead to recreate the output files without re-running all the tests.  If you can be confident that the output files do not need to be recreated, either, then you can just run `make`.

Moreover, if you are using Automake in conjunction with Autoconf, then your Makefiles are built with tooling that detects when `configure`'s m4 source, normally `configure.ac`, has changed, therefore requiring a reconfiguration.  As long as the `Makefile` generated by Automake-based `configure` remains, you can just run `make`, and it will do the right thing.  If the `Makefile` is missing, then you needed to run `configure` or `config.status` anyway.

Additionally, you could consider using a shared cache file for all your configure scripts, by specifying that file to each one via the `--config-cache` option.  That should reduce the time each `configure` script consumes by avoiding redundant testing.